# How to post on fb using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook apis to post on my testing account using php. The following code does the job for me and it works. If I log in with my account I can see the post, but if I use another account the post does not show. I have modified the privacy setting to public but still. I went to facebook's documentation,but I couldn't really find something to solve my problem. Can anyone help???

Thanks in advanced

```
function fb_post($post, $msg, $url, $pic) {
  $temp_array = queryFBTable($post);
  if (count($temp_array) == 0) return;



// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
  // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  $config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional
  $fb = new Facebook($config);

  // define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
  // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

  $params = array();
  if(isset($temp_array['AccessToken'])) {
    $params['access_token'] = $temp_array['AccessToken'];
  }
  if(isset($msg)) {
    $params['message'] = $msg;
  }
  if(isset($url)) {
    $params['link'] = $url;
  }
  if(isset($pic)) {
    $params['picture'] = $pic;
  }
    //"name" => "yooo",
    //"caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
    //"description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."


  // post to Facebook
  // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
  try {
    //tim .. 1471145939793099
    // van .. 1491737127730006
    // mc .. 796523467054680
    $ret = $fb->api("/".$temp_array['userID']."/feed", 'POST', $params);
    echo "<br>Successfully posted to Facebook account ".$post.". <br/>";
  } 
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: The app is in **Sandbox (development) mode**

Comment: @AdamAzad I don't think so, how do you do that?? there is any link you can provide please??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/review-status/ you can see make the app live & public